# Delete specific part of String in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a string which comes as **Filename [1234568]**. I need to delete the square bracket part of the string and just get the filename. How can we retrieve just the file name?

Comment: what the OP you expect

Comment: Just the **Filename**

Comment: you mean you need `Filename` or `1234568` or `Filename 1234568`

Comment: better you provide what will be sample input and what you expect in output...

Comment: Sample input would be Filename [12345678] and output should be Filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below Regex may help you

```
NSMutableString *str = [@"Filename [1234568]" mutableCopy];
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression         
                              regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\[.+?\\]"
                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                              error:NULL];

NSString *newStr = [regex replaceMatchesInString:str 
                      options:0 
                        range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])  
                 withTemplate:@""];
```